# Is there any practical difference in using min vs. max-width in media queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've read that min-width media queries means you are designing from mobile up, and max-width media queries from desktop down. But is the result of `min-width` and `max-width` media queries not basically the same if you keep good design practices in mind?

Is one of the two recommended over the other as best practice, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of mobile vs desktop design, mobile first helps you to really think about what's important first, which is of course the content. Instead of taking things away, you are now designing building upwards.

`min-width` and `max-width` media queries are used in the way you've said for a pretty obvious reason when you think about it. `min-width` is good for mobile first because you're adding in elements, and to do that with mobile first you'd have to specify which elements display only on a bigger screen - `min-width` specifies a bigger screen, et voila.

So, in answer to your question, it depends. If you agree, like most, that mobile first is the best design principle at the moment, then `min-width` is the choice you should make, so you can add in the content to the next screen size up. Vice versa, too. If you think neither is the best way, then the world's your oyster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both in your media query. Then any device that falls in the range of the min and max will use the following css. You can set as many media queries as you need.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .hidden-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

For the example above, any item with the class `.hidden-desktop` will be hidden on these devices. This my be a feature you only want to be visible on lower resolution devices.

I personally use ranges over a single min or max-width. There are so many different mobile devices out there, I think the design will dictate how many break points you need to set. I usually end up with 2 - 4. 1 for handheld devices, 1 for tablets, 1 for desktops. Depending on the design I sometimes add query for large displays like 27in. monitors etc...